# how to show diferent index array on php as same position

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have data like this:

```
echo var_dump($rank);

int(13) int(3) int(5) int(1) int(2) int(7) int(8) int(4) int(10) int(14) int(12) int(9) int(6) int(11)

===========================================================================================
echo var_dump($id_student);

string(2) "18" string(2) "19" string(2) "20" string(2) "21" string(2) "22" string(2) "23" string(2) "24" string(2) "25" string(2) "26" string(2) "27" string(2) "28" string(2) "29" string(2) "30" string(2) "31"
```

how to display $ rank data so it matches the $ id_student index array?

```
ex : if $id_student = 18 show $rank = 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foreach` to loop students and with index of every student you can easily get his/her ranks.

```
foreach($id_student as $index => $student){
    echo $student.' rank is '. $rank[$index];
}
```

Comment: i got an error 
````
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: @Nomaden $id_student is not array ?

Comment: Yes, $id_student is not array

Comment: @Nomaden so first of all. you must put every $id_student to array. with array you can use my answer and you can sync your indexes.